# I have a for loop which is supposed to iterate through the list, but it doesn't go as expected

Tags: python

hi so i have a function here:

```
def all_alpha(words: List[str]) -> bool:

    >>> all_alpha(['abcdefg', 'abc123', 'hey', 'lol'])
    False
    >>> all_alpha(['nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you', '!'])
    True
    """

    for ch in words:
        return ch.isalpha()
```

however using the first example, it returns True but when I print `ch.isalpha()` it returns `T, F, T, T`. I don't know what went wrong that it seems only returns `True` for the very first word

Answer (score 0):

```
def all_all_alpha(words):
    for word in words:
        if not word.isalpha():
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: You can change the body of the first for loop to `if not word.isalpha(): return False`. `isalpha` checks the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

```
def all_all_alpha(words: List[str]) -> bool:
    """Return True if and only if each string in words is an alphabetic string.
    A string is an alphabetic string if and only if each character is 
    alphabetic. 

    Precondition: words contains no empty strings

    >>> all_all_alpha(['try', 'csc108', 'for', 'fun'])
    False
    >>> all_all_alpha(['I', 'know', 'an', 'old', 'lady'])
    True
    """

    reuturn all([word.isalpha() for word in words])
```

or:

```
def all_all_alpha(words: List[str]) -> bool:
    """Return True if and only if each string in words is an alphabetic string.
    A string is an alphabetic string if and only if each character is 
    alphabetic. 

    Precondition: words contains no empty strings

    >>> all_all_alpha(['try', 'csc108', 'for', 'fun'])
    False
    >>> all_all_alpha(['I', 'know', 'an', 'old', 'lady'])
    True
    """

    return ''.join(words).isalpha()
```

You want to consider all letters not just those of the first string in the list.